# Two-piece mail server, working out sender_login and verified_recipient validation

Tags: authentication, smtp, postfix, dovecot

### **TL:DR** I'm trying to figure out how to get one postfix server to ask another whether a incoming email's recipient address is valid, or if an outgoing email's sender address is a valid email/alias for the logged in user.

Full version:

So I am self hosting my mail server, however being on a residential ISP, I can't really make use of my WAN IP (not static, and undoubtedly the IP block will be on spam lists everywhere) so I also have a small VPS that acts as a relay for all mail connections. (this actually had the unexpected benefit that when my home internet is down for any reason, the VPS just tells incoming mail delivery that there is a temporary error and to try again later in the day, as opposed to just being unable to find the server)

My current set up is Postfix for SMTP and SUBMISSION, Dovecot for IMAP. My virtual domains, users and aliases are stored in a MariaDB instance on my home network.

The VM on my home network is connected to the VPS through a VPN connection.

If a mail client is on my home network, all connections just go straight to the VM, and if I send mail, Postfix relays to the VPS and sends it on its way. When I'm away from home, everything connects to the VPS, which talks back and forth to the home VM for it's mail data and authentication, all transparently to the outside world.

For Dovecot this is very easily configured, as I just needed to point it at the IP provided by the VPN connection as an `imapc` mail_location and use the `imap` passdb driver. All the rest of the configuration for dovecot lives on the VM at home, so if I change, say, from using MariaDB to a LDAP server for the user info, or alter server-side rules, I only need to change them in one place.

For postfix however, I haven't been able to neaten it's configuration up quite as well. I've had to duplicate most of the settings on the VM at home on the VPS as well, so if I want to change where the usernames and passwords are getting validated, or the `virtual_alias_maps` are stored, I need to change it in two places. Additionally, I've had to set up a proxy port on the VM at home to funnel the SQL queries from the VPS through the VM and over to my container that has my databases. Messy.

So I'm wondering if there is a set of options I can set on the VPS's instance of Postfix to just point back at the VM through an SMTP or SASL connection to validating incoming and outgoing mail, both that incoming mail is addressed to a valid recipient and outgoing mail is label from a valid address linked to the user logged in. (I might be the only human user on this server, but I've got a bunch of other software that I've given independent users for delivering mail notification for errors as well as notifying me of available updates in different places)